# sorting enum for UI purpose

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

Say we have a UI and in this UI we have a dropdown. This dropdown is filled with the translated values of an enum.

Bow, we have the possibility to sort by the int-value of the enum, by the name of the enum, and by the translated name of the enum.

But what if we want a different sorting than the 3 mentioned above. how to handle such a requirement?

Comment: What kind of sorting would that be?

Comment: a useful :) typically one which is requested by another person who thinks it should be in a way (other than the way the developer set the int values)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Implement your own `IComparer`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test {
    class Program {

        enum X { 
            one,
            two,
            three,
            four
        }

        class XCompare : IComparer<X> {
            public int Compare(X x, X y) {
                // TBA: your criteria here
                return x.ToString().Length - y.ToString().Length;
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<X> xs = new List<X>((X[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(X)));
            xs.Sort(new XCompare());
            foreach (X x in xs) {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the Linq extension [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx), and perform whatever comparison magic you want:

```
// order by the length of the value 
SomeEnum[] values = (SomeEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum));
IEnumerable<SomeEnum> sorted = values.OrderBy(v => v.ToString().Length);
```

Then wrap the different sorting alternatives into methods, and invoke the right one based on user preferences/input.

Answer (score 3):

`IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy(Func<T, TKey>, IComparer<TKey>)`

Answer (score 1):

Sort FileSystemRights enum using Linq and bind to WinForms comboBox:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = ((FileSystemRights[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(FileSystemRights))).
 OrderBy(p => p.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhapse you could create an extension method for the Enum class, like this:

... first the declaration...

```
public enum MyValues { adam, bertil, caesar };
```

...then in a method...

```
MyValues values = MyValues.adam;
string[] forDatabinding = values.SpecialSort("someOptions");

...The extension method... 

public static class Utils
    {
        public static string[] SpecialSort(this MyValues theEnum, string someOptions)
        {
            //sorting code here;
        }
    }
```

And you could add different parameters to the extension metod for different sort options etc.