# OrderBy on Enum.GetValues()

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I'm populating a `DropDownList` in MVC 4 from an `enum` and I want to order the enum values from largest to smallest. However, there doesn't seem to be a direct way of approaching this. Currently, I'm using this code to add to a dictionary with the key being the ID and the value being the display text:

```
var priorities = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Models.Priority)).OfType<Models.Priority>().ToList();

for (int i = priorities.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Models.Priority priority = priorities[i];
    prioritiesDictionary.Add((int)priority, "Priority " + ((int)priority).ToString());
}
```

I don't believe that putting enum values into a list and looping backwards is the most efficient method. There are only four values in the enum, but is there a better way to perform an `OrderBy` operation on what is returned from `Enum.GetValues`? I know it might be minimal performance impact doing it the way I am, but I want to know for larger enums.

Comment: user OrderByDescending as you already suggested

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299056/sorting-enum-for-ui-purpose/1299078#1299078

Comment: I do not believe you should care about performance unless your enum contains hundreds of values which would not make sense. You could simplify your code and make it more readable by using a LINQ query.

Comment: Enum values ARE ALREADY ordered by their unsigned values ascending. This is by design:
"The elements of the array are sorted by the binary values of the enumeration constants (that is, by their unsigned magnitude)"
(Remaks here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sounds like you just want:

```
var priorities = ((Models.Priority[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(Models.Priority)))
                                          .OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

Or to avoid quite as many brackets:

```
var priorities = (Models.Priority[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(Models.Priority));
var ordered = priorities.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

It's not clear how your current code is helping you, by giving you a dictionary - but the above will definitely give you a sequence of enum values, ordered from highest to lowest. You don't need to cast to `int`, because enum values of the same type are already comparable to each other.

If you need a list, just call `ToList()` after the `OrderByDescending` call.

Answer (score 15):

What about this:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Models.Priority))
    .Cast<Models.Priority>()
    .OrderByDescending(x => (int) x)
    .ToList();
```

You shouldn't use `OfType<T>()` in this style of logic because that silently throws away non-matching items. In this case a non-matching item would indicate a serious error or misuse.

If the expectation is that all items will already be a certain type, then we use `Cast<T>()`.

> `OfType<T>` is a *filter* operation, it is intended for use in scenarios where we know some items **can not** be cast to the expected type. `OfType<T>` is therefore useful in lists that might contain `null` valued items.
>
> `OfType<T>` is commonly used in expressions that operate over untyped or `object` enumerations like *Type Attribute* or when the enumeration is a base type and you only want objects of a specific implementation, or that implement a specific interface.

Comment: That's why `OfType` is useful for some `filter by type`, however I think it can be used in this case because the input element is surely `Models.Priority`

Comment: Yes it will produce the same result here, but if for some reason you made a mistake then you would want an error and not silent data corruption. Cast guards against bugs by informing the developer that he made a mistake.; (Yes, OfType has valid use cases... Just rarely.)

Comment: `OfType<T>` is very useful, _rarely_ is not fair statement, rarely in _your_ codebase but commonly in TPH schemas or models that make heavy use of interfaces. It is true that `OfType` discards objects that do not match, there are many cases where this is expected. I Agree that `Cast<T>` in this case is more appropriate than `OfType` but don't pollute the internet with blanket statements that are not helpful or correct.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I think you are correct. I'll let the comment stand for it's other content. Your edit is very welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the above, I create a reusable function...

```
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TEnum> Sort<TEnum>()
    {
        return ((TEnum[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof (TEnum))).OrderBy(x => x.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to declare an enumeration helper that can be used like so:

```cs
Enum<MyEnum>.ValuesAscending
```

Here is the helper

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
...
  public static class Enum<T>
    where T : struct, Enum
  {
    public static readonly IReadOnlyList<T> ValuesAscending = Enum.GetValues( typeof( T ) ).Cast<T>().Distinct().OrderBy( v => v ).ToArray();
    public static readonly IReadOnlyList<T> ValuesDescending = Enum.GetValues( typeof( T ) ).Cast<T>().Distinct().OrderByDescending( v => v ).ToArray();
    public static readonly IReadOnlyList<string> NamesAscending = Enum.GetNames( typeof( T ) ).OrderBy( s => s ).ToArray();
    public static readonly IReadOnlyList<string> NamesDescending = Enum.GetNames( typeof( T ) ).OrderByDescending( s => s ).ToArray();
  };
```

Note: `ValuesAscending` and `ValuesDescending` both eliminate duplicates and will still work with enum types other than `int`. The lists are also cached using the magic of static members of static classes, though I can't guarantee thread safety, if you need that. If using all four, you could also use `.Reverse().ToArray()` on the descending ones to save some time.

If you want a few more helpers, I have a more extensive version here: https://github.com/cgbeutler/CSharpEnumExt

Comment: Nitpicking (may be): as you capture this in a readonly static, these lists will leave forever. You may avoid 2 objects by using `.ToArray()` to conclude instead of `ToList()`.

Comment: Yeah, `ToArray` would work too. I only had that in there cuz I pulled it from a bigger file that used the list for binary searches.

Comment: This one is the best (with constrained struct for the IComparable)!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.binarysearch?view=net-6.0#system-memoryextensions-binarysearch-2(system-readonlyspan((-0))-1)